# Prove $3^n \ge n^3$ by induction

Tags: inequality, induction, alternative-proof, natural-numbers

Yep, prove $3^n \ge n^3$, $n \in \mathbb{N}$.

I can do this myself, but can't figure out any kind of "beautiful" way to do it.

**The way I do it is:**

Assume $3^n \ge n^3$

Now,

$(n+1)^3 = n^3 + 3n^2 + 3n + 1$,

and $\forall{} n \ge 3$,

$3n^2 \le n^3, \,\, 3n + 1 \le n^3$

Which finally gives $(n+1)^3 \le 3n^3 \le 3^{n+1}$ by our assumption.

Now just test by hand for n=1,2,3 and the rest follows by induction.

**Anyone got anything simpler?**

Comment: Looks elegant to me

Comment: To be extremely precise, I think you should also prove $3n^2 \le n^3$ and $3n + 1 \le n^3$: these inequalities are not obvious at all.

Comment: @dado But this inequalities hold only only if $x \ge 3$, so again he has to check $n = 1,2$

Comment: @dado Actually they are pretty obvious here's short proof.

$$3n^2 \le n^3$$
$$3n^2 \le n \cdot n^2$$
$$3 \le n$$

Comment: $$3n + 1 \le n^3$$
$$4n \le n^3 $$
$$4 \le n^2 $$
$$2 \le n$$

Comment: Similar question: [Prove through induction that $3^n > n^3$ for $n \geq 4$](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/503842/prove-through-induction-that-3n-n3-for-n-geq-4).

Answer (score 2):

**Basis:**

$n = 1$

$$3^1 \ge 1^3 \implies 3 \ge 1\text{, which is true}$$

**Inductive hypothesis**

Let $n=k$ and also let this inequality hold:

$$3^k \ge k^3$$

**Inductive step**

We'll prove that it also holds when $n=k+1$

$$3^{k+1} \ge (k+1)^3$$
$$3^k \cdot 3 \ge k^3 + 3k^2 + 3k + 1$$
$$3^k + 3^k + 3^k \ge k^3 + 3k^2 + 3k + 1$$

Now obviously as $3^k \ge k^3$ by the inductive hypothesis it's enough to show that

$$2 \cdot 3^k \ge 3k^2 + 3k + 1$$

Note that for every $k \ge 2$, this inequality holds $3k^2 \ge 3k + 1$

$$2 \cdot 3^k \ge 6k^2$$
$$3^k \ge 3k^2$$

This is true for every $k \ge 3$

Now you can prove the other 2 cases $n = 1,2$ to give a complete proof.

Comment: How do you go from this line

$$3^k + 3^k + 3^k \ge k^3 + 3k^2 + 3k + 1$$

To this line:

$$2 \cdot 3^k \ge 3k^2 + 3k + 1$$?

Comment: @LovesLinearAlgebra There's no an implication between the lines. I want to prove the inequality in the second line, as the adding $3^k \ge k^3$, which follows from the inductive hypothesis we get the wanted inequality. Anyway I will fix the answer and make it more clear

Answer (score 1):

Show true for $n=1,2,3$, and assume true for $k$. Then note that $3^{k+1} = 3^{k}\cdot 3 \geq 3\cdot k^3 = (3^{1/3}\cdot k)^3$ (by our assumption). Now, for $k\geq 3$, we see that $3^{1/3}\cdot k \geq k+1$ and the result follows.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know about beauty, but after verifying the inequality for the first three cases, one can use the fact that $64\lt81$ to conclude that $3\log(1+{1\over3})\lt\log3$.  By combining this with the induction hypothesis, it follows that for $n\ge3$,

$$\begin{align}
3\log(n+1) &= 3\log n + 3\log(1+{1\over n})\cr
&\le 3\log n +3\log(1+{1\over3}) \cr
&\lt n\log3+\log3\cr
&=(n+1)\log3
\end{align}$$

Answer (score 0):

Here is another argument, but it's not necessarily simpler than yours:

1) If $n=1$, $3^1=3\ge1=1^3$;  if $n=2$, $3^2=9\ge8=2^3$; and if $n=3$, $3^3=3^3$.

2) Now assume that $3^n\ge n^3$ for some integer $n\ge3$.

Then $\displaystyle\frac{1}{n}\le\frac{1}{3}$, so $\displaystyle\frac{(n+1)^3}{n^3}=\big(1+\frac{1}{n}\big)^3\le\big(\frac{4}{3}\big)^3=\frac{64}{27}\le3$, so

$\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;3^{n+1}=3(3^n)\ge3n^3\ge(n+1)^3$.

Comment: Nice!  But you want to drop the final $3$ from in front of the $(n+1)^3$.

Comment: @Barry Cipra Thanks for this correction!